# Hide element on select within table cell - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I followed this app to build a table with custom cells: https://github.com/awseeley/Custom-Table-Cell

I am trying to expand a cell and show different content when the cell is clicked.

Here is what I have in my view controller:

```
var cellTapped:Bool = true
var currentRow = 0;

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //CODE TO BE RUN ON CELL TOUCH

    let selectedRowIndex = indexPath
    currentRow = selectedRowIndex.row

    let cell:TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TblCell

    cell.image.hidden = true

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == currentRow {
        if cellTapped == false {
            cellTapped = true

            return 141
        } else {
            cellTapped = false
            return 70
        }
    }
    return 70
}
```

The cell expands when it is clicked and shrinks when it is clicked again. But the image does not hide. How do I get the image to hide? Is there a better way to show another custom .xib file when the cell is selected and have an expand/collapse effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should add this implement below to your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       if indexPath.row == currentRow {
           if cellTapped == false {
               cell.image.hidden = false
           } else {
               cell.image.hidden = true
           }
       }

       return cell
   }
   ```

And `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you should remove wrong code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //CODE TO BE RUN ON CELL TOUCH

    let selectedRowIndex = indexPath
    currentRow = selectedRowIndex.row
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

2. If you want use want use tableView.beginUpdate() for better animation, you can reference to my demo:

   [Demo hide image on cell](https://github.com/vienvu89/DemoResizeTableViewCell)

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you, but this just removes the image permanently from the cell, how do I get it to remove the image only when the cell is selected and show the image when it is no longer selected?

Comment: @KatieH You want show hide only one cell on `tableView` or each cell will show/hide when clicked?

Comment: I only want to hide the image on when cell when it it active, when it is clicked/selected. When the cell is not longer selected, the image should appear again.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiarized with it, but you can look at Stack View. I think it's can help you doing what you want:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views